# Properly display contact information

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm making an Android app, in which I display contact info. This information comes from a webAPI, in the form of JSON. What I get in is a bunch of strings like first name, last name, phone number etc.

Currently I've got a setup like this:

```
JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0);
TextView contact = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact);
String contactString = "";
contactString += object.getString("Voorletters") + " ";
contactString += object.getString("Voorvoegsel").trim() + " ";
contactString += object.getString("Achternaam") + "\n";
contactString += object.getString("Email")+"\n";
if (!object.getString("Mobiel").isEmpty()) {
    contactString += object.getString("Mobiel") + "\n";
}
if (!object.getString("Mobiel2").isEmpty()) {
    contactString += object.getString("Mobiel2") + "\n";
}
if (!object.getString("Telefoon").isEmpty()) {
    contactString += object.getString("Telefoon") + "\n";
}
if (!object.getString("Telefoon2").isEmpty()) {
    contactString += object.getString("Telefoon2") + "\n";
}
contact.setText(contactString);
Linkify.addLinks(contact,Linkify.ALL);
```

This works fine, you can tap the e-mail and phone numbers just fine. My only problem is, when you tap a phone number, my tablet gives a popup showing ONLY the phone number, and an option to add that phone number to the contact list.

What I'd like to achieve is to make android see that this information is linked. That instead of just the phone number showing up, any time you tap anywhere in the textview, a popup comes up showing all contact information and an option "add to contacts", preferably like [image: the default android contact popup]

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: do you want to show custom dialog for contact info?

Comment: By different options , if you mean the "Share via" options , then that can be done by firing an intent with ACTION_SHARE, and all those applications that accept such intent will show up.

Comment: @praveenSharma I do not necessarily need a custom dialog, launching a default one would be fine as well.

Comment: @cafebabe1991 No, sorry. I guess that wasn't clear enough, don't really want to share the contact information. I have the contact information, I just want to display it nicely.

Comment: see if you want to display contact information inside your app then you need to make your UI. The picture you have share is just default share option using Intent

Comment: @praveenSharma I meant the left half of that picture... When I, for instance, open a vcf file it shows a nice popup containing the info, using the default contact app. That's kinda what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to iago I have managed to find a solution. Apparently it's impossible to use the default contact app to show custom information, but it is possible to create a contact and show that one. So what I've done is the following:

I've made a small library with a Contact class. This contact class contains all the information I want my contact to have. In there, I've made a function that checks if the e-mail address provided exists in the contact list. If so, this function will launch an intent displaying the contact information. Otherwise, it'll launch an intent allowing the user to add the contact to their contact list. In full this class looks like this:

```
package nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.contact;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @author Daniël van den Berg
 * @date 9/29/2015.
 * <p/>
 * The Contact class is a simple bridge that allows for users to add or view a contact based on entered details.
 */
public class Contact {
    public final String name;
    public final String email;
    public final String mobile;
    public final String mobile2;
    public final String phone;
    public final String phone2;

    /**
     * Creates a new contact. This contact can then be used to display or be added to the contact list.
     * @param name The name of the contact.
     * @param email The email of the contact.
     * @param mobile The first mobile number of the contact.
     * @param mobile2 The second mobile number of the contact.
     * @param phone The first phone number of the contact.
     * @param phone2 The second phone number of the contact.
     */
    public Contact(String name,
                   String email, String mobile, String mobile2, String phone, String phone2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.mobile2 = mobile2;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.phone2 = phone2;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a human-readable representation of this object. 
     * It will filter out any phone numbers that have been set to "" or null.
     * This will return the following string:<br>
     * <code>
     * name<br>
     * email<br>
     * mobile<br>
     * mobile2<br>
     * phone<br>
     * phone2
     * </code>
     * The line-breaks are implemented as "\n"
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String contactString = name + "\n";
        contactString += email + "\n";
        if (!mobile.isEmpty() &&
            !mobile.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            contactString += mobile + "\n";
        }
        if (!mobile2.isEmpty() &&
            !mobile2.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            contactString += mobile2 + "\n";
        }
        if (!phone.isEmpty() &&
            !phone
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            contactString += phone + "\n";
        }
        if (!phone2.isEmpty() &&
            !phone2
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            contactString += phone2;
        }
        return contactString;
    }

    /**
     * showOrCreateContact will show or create the contact. This function will search the phone's address book for any contact with the same e-mail address. 
     * If any is found, it will open that contact using the default contact app. If not, it will open an "add contact" dialog.
     * @param context The context to use when firing intents.
     */
    public void showOrCreateContact(Context context) {
        final Cursor
                cursor
                = context
                .getContentResolver()
                .query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[]{
                                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID,
                                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY},
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA +
                        " LIKE '" +
                        email +
                        "'",
                        null,
                        null);
        Log.d(
                "Contact",
                "Count " + cursor.getCount());
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final String id = cursor.getString(0);
            Log.d("Contact", "ID " + id);
            Intent
                    intent
                    = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String
                    lookupKey
                    = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY));
            long contactId = cursor.getLong(
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
            Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);
            intent.setData(uri);

            context.startActivity(intent);
            return;
        }

        Intent
                intent
                = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        intent.putExtra(
                ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME,
                name);
        intent.putExtra(
                ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL,
                email);
        ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<>();


        if (!mobile.isEmpty() &&
            !mobile
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            data.add(
                    addPhoneNumber(
                            mobile,
                            "Mobiel"));
        }
        if (!mobile2.isEmpty() &&
            !mobile2
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            data.add(
                    addPhoneNumber(
                            mobile2,
                            "Mobiel 2"));
        }

        if (!phone.isEmpty() &&
            !phone
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            data.add(
                    addPhoneNumber(
                            phone,
                            "Telefoon"));
        }
        if (!phone2.isEmpty() &&
            !phone2
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            data.add(
                    addPhoneNumber(
                            phone2,
                            "Telefoon 2"));
        }
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(
                ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA,
                data);
        intent.putExtra(
                "finishActivityOnSaveCompleted",
                true);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    private ContentValues addPhoneNumber(String number, String text) {

        ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
        row.put(
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        row.put(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                number);
        row.put(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);
        row.put(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL,
                text);
        return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Intents.Insert.ACTION which will call up the Contacts application with the requisite data. All you need to do is add the required data such as Phone number, Email, etc as intent extra.

```
// Creates a new Intent to insert a contact
Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.Insert.ACTION);
// Sets the MIME type to match the Contacts Provider
intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

// Inserts a name
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.NAME, name);

// Inserts an email address
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.EMAIL, mEmailAddress.getText());

startActivity(intent);
```

More information

[Insert a Contact using Intent](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html#InsertContact)

[Intent.Inserts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you look into using the Gson class to parse your JSON object efficiently. It would something like,

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0);    
ContactClass person = gson.fromJson((String)object, ContactClass.class);
```

Gson will map all of your incoming contacts from the json object.
After that I would suggest that you create a custom adapter to display the contact info which ever way you want.
I don't think there is a template to display contacts so you have to create your own adapter and xml view.